# Move wordpress to root

Tags: wordpress, root

A friend of mine asked me to help him to move his website from `website.com/wp` to the root `website.com/`

Its Wordpress installation is automatized by some script on `register.it`

I followed this [guide](https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress), I log on, I changed both WordPress and Site Address from `website.com/wp` to `website.com` and saved.

Then from the ftp, I copied and pasted all my `public/www/wp` one step higher to `public/www/` but the site was down and I couldn't even reach `website.com/wp-admin` or `website.com/wp-login.php`

Then I restored one of the backups I had and I tried this other [guide](http://askwpgirl.com/how-do-i-move-wordpress-from-a-subdirectory-to-the-root-directory/), I moved the index.php one step higher by changing

```
/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );
```

to

```
/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp/wp-blog-header.php' );
```

And of course this didn't work neither..

Now I start also wondering if that one was the real Wordpress root, this is the structure

[image]

How can I make the website be reachable on the root?

Comment: Maybe the domain name has been configured to point at the /wp directory? You would also have to change some stuff in the wp_meta table

Comment: @ham-sandwich how could I check that? Which is the simplest way to move a wordpress site to the root?

Comment: I did a bit more information. When a user visits www.example.com, are they redirected to www.example.com/wp or does www.example.com/wp just load as example.com?

Comment: @ham-sandwich I restored everything now, also the index.php... Which way do you suggest me to go?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.

I tried the whole time playing with the /public/www folder, while instead the real Wordpress root was under /web/